# How to generate new Meteor login tokens (server side) in order to make a quick login link

Tags: meteor

Meteor has a `loginWithToken` method, and there are `resume` tokens in the user object. So one can login using one of these tokens with `loginWithToken`. That works.

Is there a way to generate new login tokens, or should I just use the resume tokens to create a quick login link?

Answer (score 23):

As Johnny said, you can use the `Accounts._generateStampedLoginToken()` function, which is actually nothing special, just the following function:

```
_generateStampedLoginToken = function () {
  return {
    token: Random.secret(),
    when: new Date
  };
}
```

anyway, to use it, here is an example:

```
// Server //

// Creates a stamped login token
var stampedLoginToken = Accounts._generateStampedLoginToken();

/**
 * Hashes the stamped login token and inserts the stamped login token 
 * to the user with the id specified, adds it to the field 
 * services.resume.loginTokens.$.hashedToken. 
 * (you can use Accounts._hashLoginToken(stampedLoginToken.token) 
 * to get the same token that gets inserted)
 */
Accounts._insertLoginToken(user._id, stampedLoginToken);


// Client //

// Login with the stamped loginToken's token
Meteor.loginWithToken(stampedLoginToken.token);
```

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the internal methods that get called to generate the tokens!

Comment: Quick question.. `Meteor.loginWithToken` is strictly client side right?

Comment: @redskins80 yes, that is correct, you could generate the token via a Meteor method call or something, my comment says otherwise, let me edit that.

Comment: Does Meteor.loginWithToken require a package?  I'm [getting errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35419371/meteor-unable-to-call-loginwithtoken-from-meteor-or-accounts)

Comment: Where are those Tokens stored?

Comment:  very helpful

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can generate new tokens by calling `Accounts._generateStampedLoginToken()`. You can call it from within a login handler.

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js#L114

Comment: How can you call this from client side?

Comment: Idk, this answer is 5 years old so I assume it's extremely out of date.

Comment: Answer is still correct. Code hasn't changed that much. ATM i use, `Meteor.methods` to call this function. Since i didn't find any Client sided API except the login function.

Answer (score 2):

it's 2015 - use one of these packages:

- poetic:accounts-passwordless
- acemtp:accounts-passwordless

http://fastosphere.meteor.com/?q=passwordless

Comment: poetic:accounts-passwordless is pretty legit