# Meteor - unable to call loginWithToken from Meteor or Accounts

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to call loginWithToken from Meteor, using the following:

`Meteor.loginWithToken(secret)`

`Accounts.loginWithToken(secret)`

but am getting

`TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'loginWithToken'`

for both.

The method [exists in Meteor](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/dc3cd6eb92f2bdd1bb44000cdd6abd1e5d0285b1/packages/accounts-base/localstorage_token.js) and is public facing (although it isn't documented), is there some package I need to include?

Answer (score 1):

This is because loginWithToken can only be called from the client.