# MeteorJS Logging in User with User Object

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts, meteor-helper

I have user object from database in my Blaze Helper file:

`Object {_id: "mFx4Fa8aPpoFweziq", services: Object, emails: Array[1], profile: Object}`

I want to login this user using above object which contains email as well as hash password.

I have following accounts packages: `accounts-password` `accounts-ui`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can login with the loginToken saved inside `services.resume.loginTokens`

Get the token from the array of tokens and use the following method

`Meteor.loginWithToken(token, callback)`

check [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/be986fd70926c9dd8eff6d8866205f236c8562c4/packages/accounts-base/localstorage_token.js#L11)

that is how meteor reads the value from localstorage and automatically log you in when you re-open the website

If you don't have access token you can create one, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15684634/how-to-generate-new-meteor-login-tokens-server-side-in-order-to-make-a-quick-l)